# Using IPC Sys V

Tags: c, linux, ipc

i have a server and a client and want to send a file from the client to the server, by using Sys V IPC. My Problem is the sending of the file, the server is creating the file but than stops at msgrcv_3 Invalid argument (last do while in the server). Maybe somebody have an idea.

Snippet of Server:

```
      while(1){
    int ausgabe=0;
  /* Messageq */ 
  if ((msqid = msgget(server_key, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666)) < 0){
    perror("msgget_1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /*  Message Empfangen */
  if((msreturn = msgrcv(msqid, (void*)&name, sizeof(struct name),0,0))<0){
    perror("msgrcv_1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }  

    result.exists = FileExists(name.file_name);
    printf("%d\n", result.exists);

  /* Message Versenden*/
  if((msreturn = msgsnd(msqid, (void*)&result, sizeof(struct result),0))<0){
    perror("msgsnd_1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
   if(result.exists == 42){
    if((msreturn = msgrcv(msqid, (void*)&data, sizeof(struct data),0,0))<0){
      perror("msgrcv_2");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    creatfile = open(data.file_name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT| O_EXCL , 0);
      if(creatfile == -1){
        perror("creratfile");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    do{
      if(msgrcv(msqid, (void*)&msg_body, sizeof(struct msg_body),0,0)<0){
        perror("msgrcv_3");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
      }
      buff_blub = write(creatfile, &msg_body.buffer, msg_body.bufsize);
      if (buff_blub < 0){
        perror("write");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      ausgabe = ausgabe+msg_body.bufsize;
    }
    while(ausgabe != data.datasize);
      chmod(data.file_name, 0644);
  }  
}
```

Snippet of the Client:

```
        strncpy(name.file_name, argv[2], sizeof(name.file_name) - 1);

  /* Message Versenden*/
    if((msreturn = msgsnd(msqid, (void*)&name, sizeof(struct name),0))<0){
        perror("msgsnd");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  /*  Message Empfangen */
    if((msreturn = msgrcv(msqid, (void*)&result, sizeof(struct result),0,0))<0){
        perror("msgrcv");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }  

    if(result.exists == 1){
        puts("File already exists");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(result.exists == 42){
        file_read = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        if (file_read > 0){
            if (fstat(file_read, &sb)==-1){
                perror("fstat");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            strncpy(data.file_name, argv[2], sizeof(data.file_name) - 1);
            data.datasize = sb.st_size;
            data.c_pid = getpid();
            if((msreturn = msgsnd(msqid, (void*)&data, sizeof(struct data),0))<0){
                perror("msgsnd");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            while((file_buffer = read (file_read, &msg_body.buffer, BUF_SIZE)) > 0){
                msg_body.bufsize = file_buffer;
                msg_body.prio = 2;
                if((msreturn = msgsnd(msqid, (void*)&msg_body, sizeof(struct msg_body),0))<0){
                    perror("msgsnd");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }   
            }
        close(file_read);
        }

    }
return 1;
}
```

the structur:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#if !defined(__MSGBSP_H)
#define __MSGBSP_H
#define BUF_SIZE 1024


struct data {
  char file_name[255];
  ssize_t datasize;
  long c_pid;
};
struct name {
    char file_name[255];
};
struct result {
  int exists;
};
struct header {
  int size;
};
struct msg_body {
    long prio;
    ssize_t bufsize;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
};
#endif
```

Comment: can't see `msgrcv_3` in your code.

Comment: It´s in the server in the last do ... while

Comment: what is the error code given ?

Comment: at the first read, you are using three structures to send messages across IPC but you are using the same message type. that is not recommended since it can create confusion at the receiver's end. secondly can you please post the complete error message and the structures used in the message transmission/reception?

Comment: The Complet error is `msgrcv_3: Invalid argument` and next line  `msgctl_exithandler: Invalid argument` i added the structur to the question

Comment: Any good reason to use the *old* IPC SySV instead of POSIX [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) ?